# No se imprimen los resultados

Tags: c++

soy nueva programando y necesito ayuda en este programa de interpolación de Lagrange, luego de realizar las operaciones necesarias cuando llega el momento de imprimir la respuesta la misma no muestra el valor de la variable correspondiente al resultado

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
        using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    int cant,n;
    float x[101],y[101], xint,yint=0,r, num, den;
    cout<<"Cantidad de Puntos:" ;
    cin>>cant;
    cout<<"Ingrese los valores (x):"    <<"\n";
    
    for(int i=1;i<=cant;i++){
        cin>>x[i];  }
    cout<<"Ingrese los valores (y):"<<"\n"  ;
    for(int i=1;i<=cant;i++){
        cin>>y[i];  }
    cout<<"\n Valor a Interpolar: ";    
    cin>>xint;
    //Fórmula lagrange
    for(int i=1;i>=n;i++){
        num=1;
        den=1;
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
            if(i!=j){
                num=num*(xint-x[j]);
                den=den*(x[i]-x[j]);}}
                r=yint+(num/den)*yint;}
        cout<<"Y interpolada es:",r;
    
    system("pause");
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Antes del primer `for`, cuando ya tienes los datos introducidos, no tienes inicializada la variable `n` y la usas en el `for`, que tampoco parece tener sentido empezar en `1` mientras `i >= n`, e incrementar en `1`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La línea 28 está mal, debería de ser:

```
    cout<<"Y interpolada es:"<<r<<endl;
```

Además, el bucle for tiene un error lógico en la condición, porque se va a preguntar: n (el valor de n es 0) es mayor o igual a 1, entonces, dirá no, 0 no es mayor o igual a 1. Las variables: cant y n, podrían contener valores basura y también los arreglos. Se debería incluir stdlib.h para poder usar system(). En conclusión, el código debería de estar así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h> 

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int cant=0,n=0;
    
    float x[101] = {}, y[101] = {}, xint=0, yint=0, r=0, num=0, den=0;
    
    cout<<"Cantidad de Puntos:";
    cin>>cant;
    cout<<"Ingrese los valores (x):"<<"\n";
    
    for(int i=1;i<=cant;i++){
       cin>>x[i];  
    }
     
    cout<<"Ingrese los valores (y):"<<"\n"  ;
    
    for(int i=1;i<=cant;i++){
        cin>>y[i];  
    }
    
    cout<<"\nValor a Interpolar: ";    
    cin>>xint;
    //Fórmula lagrange
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        num=1;
        den=1;
            
    for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
        
        if(i!=j){
            
        num=num*(xint-x[j]);
        den=den*(x[i]-x[j]);
        
        }
        
        }
        
        r=yint+(num/den)*yint;
    }
                
    cout<<"Y interpolada es:"<<r<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Hola! lo añadí pero sigue sin imprimir la respuesta

Comment: Buenas! Ya lo arregle, gracias. Por favor, lee [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). También mira [Tour Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Cómo eres nueva programando, estos tutoriales/canales te pueden ayudar: [Curso C++](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWtYZ2ejMVJlUu1rEHLC0i_oibctkl0Vh) [Pau fernandez](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChcPJ2TM1fznBZMAlgzRy9Q) [DiscoDuroderoer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEzsgYrYzOCOcwmjhu_pngw)

Answer (score 1):

Hay que corregir tu código. En la línea 28 tienes esto:
**cout<<"Y interpolada es:",r;**

pero debería quedar así:
**cout<<"Y interpolada es:"<<r << endl;**

Comment: Es cierto, pero el bucle for tiene un error logico y otras cosas mas...